# ASP.net/Classic ASP: Sales Tax Rate Calculation via Zip?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Are there any ways to calculate Sales Tax Rates via some sort of web service or third-party application? Are there anything other than third-party apps for this?

I have a Classic ASP application that simply needs some way to calculate a rate based on an address or zip. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are companies that specialize in (and charge large amounts of money for) sales and use tax data for various US jurisdictions. One of them (no affiliation with me, BTW) can be found at [SalesTax.com](http://salestax.com). Contact them for current pricing and frequency of the data being updated.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of... I didn't realize there was a market for selling the actual rates.

Comment: @jlrolin: Of course there is. Someone has to keep it up to date, especially in these economic times. The company I linked to used to provide monthly updates to their data that were pretty large, because of the many changes. @Nathan: You sound surprised. <g> I quit being surprised about the market for odd things when I heard about used celebrity undergarments and strangely shaped potato chips being auctioned off on eBay. :-)

Comment: Well... it was wishful thinking on my part. I figured that the government might have some sort of released table structure, lol. Real wishful thinking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a web service you can use for $22 a month.

http://www.zip2tax.com/z2t_services.asp

They sell files per State as well, and for $588 a year you can get updated monthly files for all 50 states.  Not sure which one best suits your needs.